# Writing a tokenizer in Python

Tags: python, regex, token, tokenize, nltk

I want to design a custom tokenizer module in Python that lets users specify what tokenizer(s) to use for the input. For instance, consider the following input:

> Q: What is a good way to achieve this? A: I am not so sure. I think I
>   will use Python.

I want to be able to provide [NLTK's sentence tokenization](http://nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html), `sent_tokenize()` as an option because it works well in many situations and I don't want to re-invent the wheel. In addition to this, I also want to provide a finer-grained tokenization builder (something along the lines of a rule-engine). Let me explain:

Assume that I provider a couple of tokenizers:

```
SENTENCE # Tokenizes the given input by using sent_tokenize()
WORD # Tokenizes the given input by using word_tokenize()
QA # Tokenizes using a custom regular expression. E.g., Q: (.*?) A: (.*?)
```

I want to support rules as follows:

1. QA -> SENTENCE: Apply the QA tokenizer first, followed by the sentence tokenizer
2. QA: Apply just the QA tokenizer

Therefore, the expected output is as follows:

**1. QA -> SENTENCE**

```
[
  ('QUESTION', 
             ('SENTENCE', 'What is a good way to achieve this?'), 
  ),
  ('ANSWER', 
             ('SENTENCE', 'I am not so sure', 'I think I will use Python')
  )
]
```

**2. QA**

```
[
  ('QUESTION', 'What is a good way to achieve this?'),
  ('ANSWER', 'I am not so sure. I think I will use Python')
]
```

What is a good design to achieve this efficiently?

Comment: are you asking what libraries to use?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Either libraries or a good extensible design pattern that is scalable. I haven't taken compilers so I just want to make sure I am not re-implementing something standard from that area.

Comment: Im not sure for lexers/grammars I have really only messed with ply ...  but that may be what your looking for ... here is a good list of parsing options : http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html ... although Im not sure if that even partially answers your question

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Thank you. I'm currently looking at it.

Comment: @2er0: My input is mostly natural text (there is no obvious structure to the whole but the idea is that I can find some patterns).

Comment: So you're not looking at `tokenizer` per se, but for parsers that can differentiate questions from normal sentences, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. I am not looking at "Question" detection as that is a separate area. I am just trying to deal with situations where the input has some regularity that I can exploit before processing it.

Comment: Whats wrong with just writing a function that takes input functions and applies them to the given text? You can include `word_tokenize`, `sent_tokenize`, and `regexp_tokenize`?

Comment: Shouldn't QA -> SENTENCE  look like ('QUESTION', ('SENTENCE', 'What is a good way to achieve this?')),

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As tokenizing is easy in Python, I'm wondering what your module is planned to provide.
I mean when starting a piece of software a good design rather comes from thinking about the usage scenarios than considering data structures first.

Your examples for expected output are a bit confusing.
I assume you want the tokenizers return name on left side and a list of tokens on right side.
I played a bit to achieve similar results, but using lists for easier handling:

```
import re

# some tokenizers
def tokzr_WORD(txt): return ('WORD', re.findall(r'(?ms)\W*(\w+)', txt))  # split words
def tokzr_SENT(txt): return ('SENTENCE', re.findall(r'(?ms)\s*(.*?(?:\.|\?|!))', txt))  # split sentences
def tokzr_QA(txt):
    l_qa = []
    for m in re.finditer(r'(?ms)^[\s#\-\*]*(?:Q|Question)\s*:\s*(?P<QUESTION>\S.*?\?)[\s#\-\*]+(?:A|Answer)\s*:\s*(?P<ANSWER>\S.*?)$', txt):  # split (Q, A) sequences
        for k in ['QUESTION', 'ANSWER']:
            l_qa.append(m.groupdict()[k])
    return ('QA', l_qa)
def tokzr_QA_non_canonical(txt):  # Note: not supported by tokenize_recursively() as not canonical.
    l_qa = []
    for m in re.finditer(r'(?ms)^[\s#\-\*]*(?:Q|Question)\s*:\s*(?P<QUESTION>\S.*?\?)[\s#\-\*]+(?:A|Answer)\s*:\s*(?P<ANSWER>\S.*?)$', txt):  # split (Q, A) sequences
        for k in ['QUESTION', 'ANSWER']:
            l_qa.append((k, m.groupdict()[k]))
    return l_qa

dict_tokzr = {  # control string: tokenizer function
    'WORD'    : tokzr_WORD,
    'SENTENCE': tokzr_SENT,
    'QA'      : tokzr_QA,
}

# the core function
def tokenize_recursively(l_tokzr, work_on, lev=0):
    if isinstance(work_on, basestring):
        ctrl, work_on = dict_tokzr[l_tokzr[0]](work_on)  # tokenize
    else:
        ctrl, work_on = work_on[0], work_on[1:]  # get right part
    ret = [ctrl]
    if len(l_tokzr) == 1:
        ret.append(work_on)  # add right part
    else:
        for wo in work_on:  # dive into tree
            t = tokenize_recursively(l_tokzr[1:], wo, lev + 1)
            ret.append(t)
    return ret

# just for printing
def nestedListLines(aList, ind='    ', d=0):
    """ Returns multi-line string representation of \param aList.  Use \param ind to indent per level. """
    sRet = '\n' + d * ind + '['
    nested = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(aList):
        if i:
            sRet += ', '
        if type(e) == type(aList):
            sRet += nestedListLines(e, ind, d + 1)
            nested = 1
        else:
            sRet += '\n' + (d + 1) * ind + repr(e) if nested else repr(e)
    sRet += '\n' + d * ind + ']' if nested else ']'
    return sRet

# main()
inp1 = """
    * Question: I want try something.  Should I?
    * Answer  : I'd assume so.  Give it a try.
"""
inp2 = inp1 + 'Q: What is a good way to achieve this?  A: I am not so sure. I think I will use Python.'
print repr(tokzr_WORD(inp1))
print repr(tokzr_SENT(inp1))
print repr(tokzr_QA(inp1))
print repr(tokzr_QA_non_canonical(inp1))  # Really this way?
print

for ctrl, inp in [  # example control sequences
    ('SENTENCE-WORD', inp1),
    ('QA-SENTENCE', inp2)
]:
    res = tokenize_recursively(ctrl.split('-'), inp)
    print nestedListLines(res)
```

Btw. Python/Lib/tokenize.py (for Python code itself) might be worth a look how to handle things.

Comment: You can probably compile and reuse the compiled regexes.

Comment: +1 First of all, thank you very much for this. I have a couple of follow-up questions: 1. Do you have suggestions on how to handle large input? Operating on chunks does not make sense to me due to regex boundaries. 2. Is there a way to convert the non-canonical tokenize into a canonical one? Given some input, it should first find the QUESTION and ANSWER and then individually apply the subsequent parts.

Comment: For 1.: (I don't know about regex bounderies) To feed large data maybe you want to consider both a) file iteration like `with open(fn) as f: for line in f:` and b) functions returning with `yield`. For 2.: Couldn't you just adapt `tokzr_QA()` to your special needs?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly then I do think you should reinvent the wheel. I would implement state machines for the different types of tokenization you want and use python dictionaries for saving the tokens.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Example state machine that will take a sentence with spaces and print out the words, of course you could do this specific example in easier ways! But with state machines in general you get linear time performance and can costumize it easily!

```
while 1:
    if state == "start":
        if i == len(text):
            state = "end"
        elif text[i] == " ":
            state = "new word"
            i = i - 1
        else:
            word.append(text[i])
    elif state == "new word":
        print(''.join(word))
        del word[:]
        state = "start"
    elif state == "end":
        print(''.join(word))
        break
    i = i + 1
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Then you can for example use this python data structure for saving your tokens. I think it's perfectly suited for your needs!

Hope this was some help.